# I need to get record from mysql between 22:00:00 AND 02:30:00

Tags: mysql, sql, between

I need to get record from mysql between 22:00:00 AND 02:30:00. I have shift master table

```
CREATE TABLE `mas_shift` (
`ShiftId` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ShiftName` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`From_Time` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`To_Time` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`In_From_Time` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`In_To_Time` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Out_From_Time` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Out_To_Time` TIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`IsActive` INT(1) NULL DEFAULT '1',
`ColorCode` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NULL',
PRIMARY KEY (`ShiftId`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `mas_shift` (`ShiftName`, `From_Time`, `To_Time`, `In_From_Time`, `In_To_Time`, `Out_From_Time`, `Out_To_Time`, `IsActive`, `ColorCode`) VALUES ('1st Shift', '08:00:00', '16:00:00', '06:00:00', '11:30:00', '13:00:00', '22:59:00', 1, '#ffee58');
INSERT INTO `mas_shift` (`ShiftName`, `From_Time`, `To_Time`, `In_From_Time`, `In_To_Time`, `Out_From_Time`, `Out_To_Time`, `IsActive`, `ColorCode`) VALUES ('2nd Shift', '16:00:00', '00:00:00', '14:30:00', '20:30:00', '23:00:00', '03:00:00', 1, '#29b6f6 ');
INSERT INTO `mas_shift` (`ShiftName`, `From_Time`, `To_Time`, `In_From_Time`, `In_To_Time`, `Out_From_Time`, `Out_To_Time`, `IsActive`, `ColorCode`) VALUES ('3rd Shift', '00:00:00', '08:00:00', '22:00:00', '02:30:00', '04:00:00', '10:30:00', 1, '#ec407a ');
```

I need to get `ShiftId` for time '23:00:00' between `In_From_Time` AND `In_To_Time`;

**Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM mas_shift as ms WHERE '23:00:00' BETWEEN ms.In_From_Time AND ms.In_To_Time;
```

For above condition I need to get `ShiftId = 3`; But I am getting empty rows.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, 2017-01-**01** 23:00:00 is between 2017-01-**01** 22:00:00 and 2017-01-**02** 02:30:00. But 23:00:00 is not between 22:00:00 and 02:30:00, because this time values belongs to same day, that started on 00:00:00 and ends on 24:00:00!
Try to use [DATETIME or TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) data type instead of [TIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html) or use elapsed time values. For example, you could use 26:30:00 instead of 02:30:00 to get expected result.

Comment: Thanks Alexander for your reply. Can you please explain how to get the ShiftId in between two times from today night to next day morning times. I am getting the time (23:05:00) from bio-metric machine and comparing that time between shift master table for getting ShiftId. Suggest any other alternative solution for solve this time.

Comment: @YathavSriTechnology, I have uploaded my answer. Does it help?

Comment: Wait i will check and revert you back Alexander

Comment: Thanks alex for quicker support. Please mark as solved. My problem is solved by following ways: I extracted the hours from time and compared whether it is greater than or equal to 22 if so i marked as 3 as Manually else between condition is working fine.